# Zend Framework 2 Element collection and Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

How can a manage to pass a collection of doctrine Entities to an Element collection?

Let me explain:

I've got an entity called *Tax*. I want to display all taxes on a form as they should be editable. My form would only contain the array of taxes, CSRF and submit button.

Comment: what do you mean by array of taxes? Elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to consider datatables.edit

http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html